# Create a complete date from partial date values in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

There are two columns that have date information. The goal is to create `date_goal` using `date_col1and` `date_col2`. These are the values of each column:

- date_col1: APR-12
- date_col2: 2012
- date_goal: 4/1/2012 *Day will always be the 1st of that month by default.

This is what I have tried so far:

```
SELECT REPLACE(LEFT('01' + '-' + date_col1, CHARINDEX('-',date_col1)-1),'-',date_col2) AS date_goal
FROM table
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extract the month from `col1` and the year from `col2` and build a date string.

```
select convert(date, '1 ' + left(date_col1, 3) + ' ' + convert(varchar(4), date_col2))
from (
    values ('APR-12', 2012)
) x (date_col1, date_col2);
```

Returns:

| date_goal |
| --- |
| 2012-04-01 |

Edit: after the question was changed from SQL Server to PostgreSQL the answer becomes

```
select cast('1 ' || left(date_col1, 3) || ' ' || cast(date_col2 as varchar(4)) as date) date_goal
from (
    values ('APR-12', 2012)
) x (date_col1, date_col2);
```